# How to proportionally elongate image down center of camera

Tags: algorithm, math

So I currently have a screen with a width of 1080 pixels. I also have a camera, centered in the middle of the screen. The camera gives me the position on a screen as a value between 0 and 1. This way, when the width of the screen is multiplied by the position, you get its placement in the screen window. See below:

so the old is

0 , .5, 1 <-- The position in the screen (X)

0, 540, 1080 <-- The screen size (Y)

X*Y = Pixel Placement

However, I would like to crop off some of the camera so it corresponds more accurately to my screen. The new is:

.25, .5, .75 <-- (X)

0, 540, 1080 <-- (Y)

What is the equation for calculating this placement? I feel like I've learned this but forgotten the method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have linear relationship

```
Y = Yleft + (X - Xleft) * (Yright - Yleft) / (Xright - Xleft)
```

For your example values

```
Yleft = 0
Yright = 1080
Xleft = 0.25
Xright = 0.75
so
Y = (X - 0.25) * 1080 / 0.5 = 2160 * (X - 0.25)

for X = 0.5 
Y = 2160 * (0.5-0.25) = 540
```